# MaterialButton disappears on setting android:background

Tags: java, android, materialbutton

When I assign a button to `android:background="@color/white"`, the button disappears behind the round corners, I know, it's related to `android:background="@color/white"`, how do I solve this problem? how to change color and make rounded corners?

##### Theme

```
<resources xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"> 
    <!-- Base application theme. --> 
    <style name="Theme.SnapChat"
        parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> 

        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item> 
        <item name="android:text">@string/button1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/yellow</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

##### Code

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:style="@style/Theme.SnapChat"
    app:cornerRadius="100dp"
/>
```

Comment: Please provide your code first.

Comment: <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SnapChat" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/button1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center|center_vertical</item>
        <item name="strokeColor">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:style="@style/Theme.SnapChat"
        app:cornerRadius="100dp" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You should use

**app:backgroundTint="@color/white"**

Comment: I'm need to button was new color and it did not influenced at rounded corners

Comment: When i change color the button corners become square and something rounded corners which i appropriated becomes square

Comment: BTW i think android:style should be android:theme.         android:theme="@style/Theme.SnapChat"

Comment: I'm not understood a what is problem

Comment: @Maksim1251 there is no "android:style" tag in your MaterialButton View. It should be android:theme

Comment: I'm fixed this mistake, it's not help

Comment: well can you clarify your quesion? you should use app:backgroundTint to change background color of a material button, not android:background

Comment: I want to button a haved rounded corners and to color was a white, when i change or just put color white or any color to button loses their rounded corners and they become a full square

Comment: you should remove "android:background" inside your theme. You should use app:backgroundTint inside your materialbutton tags. I am telling you same answers, and confused that what you are trying to do.

Comment: Look https://postimg.cc/zLqSMdCx

Comment: DID YOU REMOVE "android:background="@color/white"" inside your theme?

Comment: Yes. i deleted "android:background="@color/white"" from themes.xml